# EF/Postgres SQL database-first approach possible?

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql

After hours of searching, I am little bit disappointed. Can anybody confirm (or not) that using EF database-first approch (I mean, using the VS EDMX degigner) is possible with an existing Postgres SQL database?

Some requirements :

- I want to use ngsql provider because it is free (but I am not sure it is working in database-first approach)
- I don't want to use the Devart Connect provider because it is not free and it is for a personal project. I can consider the express version but I don't think it is working on design mode.

Cheers

Comment: @marc_s ...what did you change to my original post ??

Comment: Ok marc_s.. sorry for the mispelled words and my bad english :(

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  A quick Google search found a [walkthrough](http://brice-lambson.blogspot.com/2012/10/entity-framework-on-postgresql.html) which did not suggest there were any special gotchas.

I will note I am quite sceptical of code first ORM frameworks as I think that they leave out key aspects of database design and thus encourage databases where no real planning for the future has occurred and so I think it is somewhat of a specialized tool, but the answer seems to be yes, it works.

Comment: Yet the OP wants to reverse engineer an already existing database, of which the quality has nothing to do with the OP's ORM.

Comment: This article describes the code-first model, which is exactly not what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 10):

This question appears on most google searches for EF Database First with Postgres and the accepted answer directs to a walk-through on CODE first not DATABASE first so I'll add a pointer to this answer which got me most of the way to solving it:

[PostgreSQL data provider missing from wizard in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478480/postgresql-data-provider-missing-from-wizard-in-visual-studio-2015)

Essentially there is a Visual Studio extension for postgres (simply search in the extensions and updates for Postgres) but I also had to modify the entity framework node in my app.config as it was added before I installed the extension to look like this:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />      
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

This added npgsql as a data provider and after I did this the data provider appears in the EF Database first wizard as an option.